# activity not displayed after the button is pressed, one-time activity with button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-activity

how After the "Splash screen" should go to the "about program" activity, which opens once, then click "I read" button, go to "Main Activity" and return should not open the "about program" at all. If you do not click on the button in the "about program" activity, the "about program" activity should open (until the button is pressed). if you have this code, please leave it. thank you.

**NEW USER (NOT CLICKED BUTTON)**
SPLASH SCREEN > INFORMATION ACTIVITY
| leave app, retry turn app |
SPLASH SCREEN > INFORMATION ACTIVITY

**NEWS USER (CLICKED BUTTON)**
SPLASH SCREEN > INFORMATION ACTIVITY > MAIN ACTIVITY
| leave app, retry turn app |
SPLASH SCREEN > MAIN ACTIVITY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold a boolean value in shared preference .
if it false navigate user to info activity .
on button click change bool value to true.
if true then navigate user to main activity.

in Splash check for boolean value

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean value= sharedpreferences .getBoolean('yourKey',false);

if(!value){

//navigate user to info activity

}else{

//navigate user to Main activity
}
```

on read button click

//.........make boolena value to true ............

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences .edit();
editor.putBoolean("yourKey", true);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: do you have a copy of the code similar to this process

Comment: "Expected 2 arguments but found 1" I have Error

Comment: boolean value = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("yourKey"),false);

Comment: ITS WORK, THANK YOU VERY MUCH ;'-)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to save with short code

To save

```
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean("KEY", true).apply();
```

Get saved boolean

```
 boolean b = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("KEY", false);
```

Comment: try to add  youractivity.this instead of context